# Jquery is removing segments from uri

Tags: jquery

I am feeding:

```
function projectTypeAdd(ref) {
    var ref
    $("#dialog-view").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width:650,
        minHeight:200,
        show:{effect: "fade", duration: 500},
        hide:"drop",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            /*
            "Edit": function() {
                window.open('update_generic.php?id=' + id + '&table=' + table, '_self');
            },
            */
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dialog-view").load("framework/helpers/project_type.php?ref=" + ref).dialog("open");
};
```

this `projectTypeAdd('update_generic.php?id=216264269&table=projects')`

But, when it opens `project_type.php` only the `id=123` makes it and not the `table=projects`, I have a feeling it has to do with the load part but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the value properly. Otherwise, the `&` will be treated as a parameter delimiter.

```
$("#dialog-view").load("framework/helpers/project_type.php?ref=" + encodeURIComponent(ref)).dialog("open");
```

You can also specify the parameters as an object, and jQuery will encode it for you:

```
$("#dialog-view").load("framework/helpers/project_type.php", {
    ref: ref
}).dialog("open");
```